# Define icon size in SP on MapView

Tags: android, icons, android-mapview, resolution, marker

Right now I set Marker icon from a bitmap using this part of code :

```
marker = googleMap.addMarker(...)
int height = 100;
int width = 100;
BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(MyImages.imageIds[item.getId()]);
Bitmap b = bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker);
marker.setIcon(icon);
```

But the marker icon is defined in pixels and doesn't have the same size on different screens.

[image: Icon size issue]

I have many different possible images to set as an icon and I don't want to have them in different sizes (to avoid huge size for the application).

What would you do to keep the same size on different devices ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with addMarker() function. May this help you.

Comment: Thank ou but the marker is already added, I updated my question to make it more visible.

Comment: Don't give width and height to the icon. better to kept different image resolution (drawable mdpi, hdpi,xhdpi,,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi)for the marker icon. In my case it work perfectly.